# C++ application crashes with atexit() error

Tags: c++, mfc, atexit

We have an install application which makes use of MFC and written in c++, It crashes intermittently with the call stack pasted. This crash happens when this application is about to finish. We can see atexit() reference in the call stack with a static variable 'svUniqueUpdates' that is being used inside a function for some computation. Is this crash really caused by atexit() and how to fix it?

## Call stack

0  Id: 3f30.8d0 Suspend: 1 Teb: 00000090`bbdf7000 Unfrozen
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00 00000090`bc1ffba8 00007ffa`7cc507b3 : 00000000`00000000 00007ff6`1fec2370 0000b408`eb7e3e32 00007ffa`7fa05d78 : Install!`TotalUpdCount'::`2'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'svUpdates''
01 00000090`bc1ffbb0 00007ffa`7cc4ce0b : 00000090`bc1ffd00 00000090`bc1ffc88 00000090`bc1ffd20 00007ffa`7cd25c80 : ucrtbase!::operator()+0xc3
02 00000090`bc1ffc10 00007ffa`7cc506e4 : 00000090`bc1ffd08 00007ffa`7cd25c80 00000000`00000000 00000090`bc1ffc78 : ucrtbase!__crt_seh_guarded_call::operator()<, & __ptr64, >+0x3b
03 00000090`bc1ffc40 00007ffa`7cc5bb69 : 00007ffa`7cd260a8 00007ffa`00000002 00000000`00000002 00000090`bc1ffc70 : ucrtbase!execute_onexit_table+0x34
04 00000090`bc1ffc70 00007ffa`7cc4f5ab : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 000001f7`ffffffff 00007ffa`684431a8 : ucrtbase!::operator()+0x65
05 00000090`bc1ffcb0 00007ffa`7cc462ce : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000090`bc1ffd00 : ucrtbase!__crt_seh_guarded_call::operator()<, & __ptr64, >+0x3b
06 00000090`bc1ffce0 00007ff6`1fd110b0 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ucrtbase!common_exit+0x5e
07 00000090`bc1ffd30 00007ffa`7d628364 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Install!__scrt_common_main_seh+0x16c
08 00000090`bc1ffd70 00007ffa`7fa0e851 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
09 00000090`bc1ffda0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21

only code using this static variable:

````
```TotalUpdCount(list<wchar_t *> &lvUpdates)
{    
list<wchar_t *>::iterator svListIter;
map<wstring,int>::iterator svVecIter;
static map<wstring,int> svUpdates;
static bool svFirst=true;

if(svFirst)
{
    svUpdates.clear();
    svFirstTime=false;
}
for (svListIter = lvUpdates.begin();
    svListIter != lvUpdates.end();
    svListIter++)
{
    wstring svTmpUpdate=*svListIter;
    svVecIter = svUpdates.find(svTmpUpdate);
    if (svVecIter == svUpdates.end())
        svUpdates.insert(make_pair(svTmpUpdate, 1));
}
nvTotalUpdatesCnt = static_cast<int>(svUpdates.size());
````

Comment: The crash is caused by the destructor for `svUpdates` which has been registered with `atexit`. It means you have a bug in your code, presumably that bug is corrupting `svUpdates`. Not clear what the bug might be from the posted code, mostly likely the problem is in some completely unrelated code.

Comment: You could try the following, either as a test or as a permanent workaround (of course it would be better to actually find the bug). Replace `static map<wstring,int> svUpdates;` with `static map<wstring,int>* svUpdates = new map<wstring,int>();` and `svUpdates.` with `svUpdates->`. Now there is no destructor for `svUpdates` and the crash may go away. But since you have a corruption bug you may just end up with something else becoming corrupted.

Comment: @john thanks for the suggestion. I will try out changing it to a pointer and see if the crash reoccurs.